# Create random function that return DateTime in range : Invalid use of a side-effecting operator

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

Consider this SQL Server code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateRandomDateTime ()
RETURNS DateTime
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateFrom DATETime = '2012-01-01'
    DECLARE @DateTo DATeTime = '2012-06-30'
    DECLARE @DaysRandom Int= 0
    DECLARE @MillisRandom Int=0
    select @DaysRandom= DATEDIFF(day,@DateFrom,@DateTo)
    SELECT @DaysRandom = ROUND(((@DaysRandom -1) * RAND()), 0)

    --get random millis
    SELECT @MillisRandom = ROUND(((99999999) * RAND()), 0)

    SELECT @DateTo = DATEADD(day, @DaysRandom, @DateTo)
    SELECT @DateTo = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @MillisRandom, @DateTo)
    RETURN @DateTo
END
```

I want to create a function that returns a random DateTime, but when I execute the code, I get :

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CreateRandomDateTime, Line 9
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.
>
> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CreateRandomDateTime, Line 12
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.
>
> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CreateRandomDateTime, Line 14
>   Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.
>
> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CreateRandomDateTime, Line 15
>   Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

But when I run the code without the body function, I get a random datetime, so it seems that I did something wrong with the function .

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Use of `RAND()` function is not allowed within a UDF. You can, as a work-around, create a View using `RAND()` then consume this views result in your UDF.

Comment: Side note: Why on earth is the return type declared as `varchar(250)`? You're computing a `datetime` - you should try to *keep* data in good data types for as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the RAND() operator outside the creation of the function, only you will have to pass it as a parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateRandomDateTime (
    @RAND FLOAT
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateFrom DATETime = '2012-01-01'
    DECLARE @DateTo DATeTime = '2012-06-30'
    DECLARE @DaysRandom Int= 0
    DECLARE @MillisRandom Int=0
    select @DaysRandom= DATEDIFF(day,@DateFrom,@DateTo)
    SELECT @DaysRandom = ROUND(((@DaysRandom -1) * @RAND), 0)

    --get random millis
    SELECT @MillisRandom = ROUND(((99999999) * @RAND), 0)

    SELECT @DateTo = DATEADD(day, @DaysRandom, @DateTo)
    SELECT @DateTo = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @MillisRandom, @DateTo)
    RETURN @DateTo
END
```

---

```
SELECT DBO.CREATERANDOMDATETIME(RAND())
```

Comment: But of course this returns a result that is a lot less "random" since it now uses the *same* value for both generating a random number of days and a random number of millis.